# How to prove non-existence of $O(2^n)$ approximation algorithm solving TSP?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, approximation, traveling-salesman

The following theorem (from "The Design of approximation algorithms" by Williamson & Shmoys, pg 43) states:

> For any $\alpha > 1$, there does not exist an $\alpha$-approximation algorithm for the
>   traveling salesman problem on $n$ cities, provided $P  \neq NP$. In fact, the existence of an $O(2^n)$-approximation algorithm for the TSP would similarly imply that $P = NP$.

This theorem is given without a proof. It only explains, before the theorem formally stated, that for any $\alpha > 1$, there does not exist an $\alpha$-approximation algorithm. This part is clear. But the claim that *the existence of an $O(2^n)$-approximation algorithm for the TSP would similarly imply that $P = NP$* is not obvious to me. Could someone give me a hint how to prove it or sketch of proof?

Comment: Try using such an algorithm to determine if a given graph is Hamiltonian.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Right. I missed that part of the discussion in the book. It says that we could set the weight of "non-edges" to $\alpha n + 2$ where $\alpha = O(2^n)$. So if the algorithm runs in $O(2^n)$ time, then it is, in fact, still polynomial of the length of input. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should answer your own question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After @YuvalFilmus' hint it turns out the answer lies in this book. The TSP can be used to solve the Hamiltonian Cycle problem by creating a new graph as following. Given $\alpha > 1$ and  a graph $G=\langle V,E \rangle$ we create a new graph $G'=\langle V',E' \rangle$ such that $w(e')= 1$ if $e\in E$, and $w(e')= \alpha n+2$ if $e\notin E$. If $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle then $G'$ has a tour of length $n$, otherwise each tour has length is at least $(\alpha+1)n + 1$.

Now we run $\alpha$-approximation algorithm for TSP and if the tour computed has cost at most $(\alpha+1)n$ then there is a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$, otherwise there doesn't. If we set $\alpha = O(2^n)$ then we have $O(2^n)$-approximation algorithm. This algorithm runs in $O(f(2^n))$ time for some polynomial $f$, but its time complexity is still polynomial in length of input. This means we would solve the Hamiltonian Cycle problem in polynomial time implying $P=NP$.

Comment: You have to be a bit careful here, and check that this reduction is polytime. Indeed, you can't choose $\alpha$ arbitrarily large – it needs to be $2^{n^{O(1)}}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus wouldn't it be $2^{n^{O(f(n))}}$ where $f(n)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: It should be $2^{\mathit{poly}(n)}$, since we need the encoding to have polynomial length.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Right, $n^{O(f(n))}$ is exponential. My mistake.